# "Saving" current state in foor loop to continue later

Tags: c, algorithm

currently I'm thinking about the following problem and maybe someone can help me:

For minecraft I want to change a lot of blocks and to prevent lags I want to change only a couple of blocks at the same time. To change a cuboid I usually use a loop like this:

```
for(int x=t.x; x<t.X; x++) 
  for(int y=t.y; y<t.Y; y++) 
    for(int z=t.z; z<t.Z; z++) {
      // ..
    }
```

where t saves the from and to coords.

Now I want to save the current progress to continue later.

Please help me im tired of thinking about it..

Comment: Do you mean you want to store states at the end of each iteration of the outermost loop?

Comment: For example I want to change all blocks in a cube. I know that I want to stop for example after 300 changes and now I need to continue filling the cube.
I think I found a solution with using while loops instead but I'm not sure right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like C. In C, a process cannot return to a given stack state after leaving the calling functions. So leaving a loop and later returning to it are not possible at the language level. In other languages, things are different. E.g. in the Pypy implementation of the Python language, [continuelets](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/stackless.html#continulet) can be used to achieve what you describe.

However, you can achieve similar ways by using your own objects to store the last counters.

```c
struct counters { int x, y, z; };

bool continueLoops(struct counters *ctrs) {
  for (; ctrs->x < t.X; ctrs->x++) {
    for (; ctrs->y < t.Y; ctrs->y++) {
      for (; ctrs->z < t.Z; ctrs->z++) {
        // ..
        if (weWantToInterruptTheLoop)
          return true;
      }
      ctrs->z = t.z;
    }
    ctrs->y = t.y;
  }
  return false;
}

void startLoops() {
  struct counters ctrs;
  ctrs.x = t.x;
  ctrs.y = t.y;
  ctrs.z = t.z;
  while (continueLoops(&ctrs)) {
    // do whatever you want to do between loops
  }
}
```

However, I don't see much benefit in the above approach, as opposed to perform the relevant operation directly within the inner loop. So I'm not sure whether this is useful for you.